# Inconsistency in lazy variable initialization between static and instance properties in Swift

Tags: swift, properties, lazy-initialization

```
struct MyStruct {
    static var x = myX()
    lazy var y = myY()
}

func myX() -> String {
    print("myX is running")
    return ""
}

func myY() -> String {
    print("myY is running")
    return ""
}

MyStruct.x = "X"
var myStruct = MyStruct()
myStruct.y = "Y"

print("Done")
```

prints:

> myX is running
> Done

In other words static lazy variable gets initialized just before assigning, while instance property is just assigned.

Comment: And what? You can use `private(set) lazy var y = myY()` to avoid accidentally setting it before it was initialised.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Nothing. Just inconsistency. They behave differently.

Comment: What is your question exactly? If you just want to ask "why", [please make it clear what kind of answer your are looking for.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5133585)